# WSO2 EMM - Device Name

Tags: android, wso2-iot

I am testing the WSO2 EMM 2.0.1 product, I would like to know if it is possible to change the name of the mobiles (android) in the EMM console.
In fact, I added some mobiles with the same model and we can not identify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use case which you trying to solve doesn't support EMM 2.0.1. I created a jira to address this issue[1]. This feature will be added into product near future.

1.https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-1578